# Fatal error: Interface 'Metadata\AdvancedMetadataFactoryInterface' not found

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm getting the following fatal error when trying to update my vendors with composer.phar:

```
$ php bin/composer.phar update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Generating autoload files

Fatal error: Interface 'Metadata\AdvancedMetadataFactoryInterface' not found in /sf2path/vendor/jms/metadata/src/Metadata/MetadataFactory.php on line 26
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Metadata\AdvancedMetadataFactoryInterface' not found in /sf2path/vendor/jms/metadata/src/Metadata/MetadataFactory.php on line 26

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

[RuntimeException]
An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.
```

Yesterday I created a clean install and it worked on my home machine. I also added a .gitignore file for the typical symfony directories (app/cache, web, vendor...):

```
/web/bundles/
/app/bootstrap*
/app/cache/*
/app/logs/*
/vendor/
/app/config/parameters.yml
```

Now when pulling from the repository I'm obviously missing the vendors so I thought I'd simply update them but now I'm getting the above error.

Here's my composer.json:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "jms/metadata": "*",
    "fpn/doctrine-extensions-taggable": "dev-master",
    "fpn/tag-bundle": "dev-master",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*",
    "friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle": "*"
},
```

Google doesn't really help so maybe anyone here had the same issue and found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how I messed up my vendors. I thought once installed they can now run on every machine but it seems something broke anyway. After including the missing class from the Git repository I got another problem with a missing Twig class so I screwed everything and reinstalled all vendors. 
Maybe I should delete the Question for being so simple but there might be the possibility of another person looking for it - so here's the simple answer:

Delete all your vendors (if there are any) and reinstall them with:

```
$php composer.phar install
```

This will initiate a fresh install of all your vendors. (I in my case only did an update)